# Error in getContentResolver when not uploading image

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to ask about error of my project.
My project (add data) have a uploading image function, when i not uploading the image, why my project get error ???

It's my script

```
for(int x = 0; x < 1; x++){
        String outFileName = DB_Path + sNama + x + ".jpg";
        InputStream myinput = null;
        try{
                myinput = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage[x]);


        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStream myoutput = null;
        try{
            myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            IOUtils.copy(myinput, myoutput);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            myinput.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        f1 = sNama = "_" + x + ".jpg";

        sFoto1 = sNama + "_" + 0 + ".jpg";
        }

    }
```

and it's the error

11-18 13:20:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 13:20:45.855: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:303)

error is

```
myinput = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage[x]);
```

Comment: Where is selectedImage defined?

Comment: i think here, is it true ??  myinput = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage[x]);